# Bullets missing in HTML UL for XHTML email template

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-lists, html-email

I am building a features table for an sales email. The html for the table renders without issue when I test it in browser, but when I add it to our internal CRM it becomes part of an xhtml email template. The issue is that the bullet points in the UL lists aren't displaying after the first item in the list.

Here is an example of the code looks once it is in the xhtml template:

```html
<td style="text-align:left;width:330px;min-height:50px;
   border-right:1px solid #cfd0d2;border-bottom:1px solid #cfd0d2;
   background-color: #ffffff;border-left:1px solid #cfd0d2;padding: 3px 5px;
   border-collapse: collapse;">

  <p style="font-family:'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'; font-size:13px;
     color:#333333;">
     Next Generation Remote Access service that manages your appointments
     and business on the go, which includes:</p>

  <ol>

    <li>

      <p>Free Android &amp; iOS apps</p>

      <p>25+ Business Reports</p>

      <p>Mobile Credit Card Processing Available</p>

      <p>Book Appointments</p>

      <p>Add &amp; Edit Clients and Pets</p>

      <p>View Grooming Notes &amp; Client History</p>

      <p>And More...</p>

    </li>

  </ol>

</td>
```

This is my original code:

```html
<td style="text-align:left;width:330px;min-height:50px;
    border-right:1px solid #cfd0d2;border-bottom:1px solid #cfd0d2;
    background-color: #ffffff;border-left:1px solid #cfd0d2;padding: 3px 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;">

    <p style="font-family:'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'; font-size:13px;
       color:#333333;">Next Generation Remote Access service that manages
       your appointments and business on the go, which includes:</p>
    <ol>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           Free Android & iOS apps</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           25+ Business Reports</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           Mobile Credit Card Processing Available</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           Book Appointments</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           Add & Edit Clients and Pets</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           View Grooming Notes & Client History</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           And More...</li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

Comment: You need each of your items to be an `<li>...</li>` instead of a `<p>...</p>`.  Each `<li>` gets a bullet, not each `<p>`. You can wrap your contents in a paragraph within the list-item if you like: `<li><p>Book Appointments</p></li>` but the list-items are necessary.

Comment: I have the list items in the <ul> tags but when I upload it to our CRM system, the software changes the <ul> <li>asdf</li> to the <p> tags.

Any idea why? Or is this an internal software issue?

Comment: `is this an internal software issue?` Yes, it sounds like lousy software.

Comment: And your question text is about UL lists, while the source has `ol` lists. There is a difference. By the way, I had to edit your question to make all the HTML visible. If you just put some HTML in the question text, it will not be shown as source.

Comment: Oh thank you. I'm new to stack exchange and still figuring everything out. I switched the ul to ol to try and see aid our CRM software would correctly display any sequential number for each item on the list. It still only displays a bullet or number for the first time and the rest of the items are missing it.

Comment: @BrianHehir You should accept the answer or at minimum comment in reply to it.

Comment: @John sorry about that. I think I've accepted it now. Still learning everything about stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `<ol>` (ordered list)
you will be able to see a cardinal number for each child `<li> element </li>` inside the `<ol>   </ol>`

Change your code into this:

```
<p style="font-family:'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'; font-size:13px; color:#333333;">Next Generation Remote Access service that manages your appointments and business on the go, which includes:</p>

        <ol>



            <li>Free Android &amp; iOS apps</li>

            <li>25+ Business Reports</li>

            <li>Mobile Credit Card Processing Available</li>

           <li>Book Appointments</li>

           <li>Add &amp; Edit Clients and Pets</li>

            <li>View Grooming Notes &amp; Client History</li>

            <li>And More...</li>



        </ol>

      </td>
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/7dUJs/

**I see that your syntax is not correct:**

```
<td style="text-align:left;width:330px;min-height:50px;
    border-right:1px solid #cfd0d2;border-bottom:1px solid #cfd0d2;
    background-color: #ffffff;border-left:1px solid #cfd0d2;padding: 3px 5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;">

    <p style="font-family:'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'; font-size:13px;
       color:#333333;">Next Generation Remote Access service that manages
       your appointments and business on the go, which includes:</p>
    <ol>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           Free Android & iOS apps</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           25+ Business Reports</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           Mobile Credit Card Processing Available</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           Book Appointments</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           Add & Edit Clients and Pets</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           View Grooming Notes & Client History</li>
       <li style="FONT-SIZE: 13px; FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana'">
           And More...</li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

**REPLACE IT WITH THIS:**

```
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:13px;
   color:#333333;">Next Generation Remote Access service that manages
   your appointments and business on the go, which includes:</p>
<ol>
   <li style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana;">
       Free Android & iOS apps</li>
   <li style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;">
       25+ Business Reports</li>
   <li style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;">
       Mobile Credit Card Processing Available</li>
   <li style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;">
       Book Appointments</li>
   <li style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;">
       Add & Edit Clients and Pets</li>
   <li style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;">
       View Grooming Notes & Client History</li>
   <li style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;">
       And More...</li>
</ol>
```

One reason could be that your CMS was missing a semicolon after Verdana inside the CSS inline-style. I changed the properties in lowercase like they should be and I also removed the quotes for those Web safe fonts just in case and added a sans-serif fallback. Let me know if it works. :)

Comment: The OP said that's what they started out with, but the "internal CRM" changes it into the malformed stuff. I think the question is clearer after my edit.